# SELECT * from SQL table using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm using a prepared statement to `SELECT *` from a MySQL table and I'm not sure how to use `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt))` to loop through and select items from the result array. This is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
    $query = "SELECT * from `wp_posts` WHERE ID=? ";
    //$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
    if($stmt){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $pid);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $dbpid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){
        ?>
    <h2 align="center"> <?php echo $row['post_title']; ?> </h2><br>
    <div class="paracenter">

        <p id="cont"><?php echo $row['post_content']; ?></p>
        <hr color="black" width="10%">

    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing wrong with Darwin's answer, but wanted to point out [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as an alternative with much lighter syntax:

```
<?php
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $username, $password, $options);
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * from `wp_posts` WHERE ID=?");
$stmt->execute([$pid]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

// Now you have a plain array to work with, database work is over
foreach ($result as $row):
?>

<h2 style="text-align:center;margin:0 auto">
    <?=$row["post_title"]?>
</h2>
<br/>
<div class="paracenter">
    <p id="cont">
        <?=$row["post_content"]?>
    </p>
    <hr style="color:black;width:10%"/>
</div>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

No need for any binding at all, and personally I find it much easier to work with.

Comment: Another advantage of PDO prepared statements is that you can name your placeholders, as `... WHERE id = :pid`. You then pass `execute` an associative array of arguments, as `execute(array(':pid' => $pid))`.

Comment: Please [do not catch errors to report them.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors). Besides, it will make syntax even more lighter.

Comment: @YourCommonSense this is a simple proof of concept. I'm not going to write a global error handling routine to answer a basic question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense like I said, I've got an open mind so it's no bother. If I'm actually doing something wrong I'd like to know, I just need more than someone saying, "that's wrong." An uncaught exception will result in a fatal error, which results in a blank page, does it not?

Comment: Of course not. Not necessarily. On a dev server with display_errors=on the error will be shown on screen. While on a live server whatever blank screens are just not a concern of a humble database wrapper. Neither should it be a concern of "a simple proof of concept."

Comment: @YourCommonSense Your point is taken about unnecessarily complicating sample code. By saying "blank screens are just not a concern of a humble database wrapper" you mean the exceptions should be caught, just higher up than the DB code? Obviously showing a blank page to a user on a live site is not an option.

Comment: Still a blank page is not necessary. If you tell your web-server to show something in case of 5xx error returned from PHP (ErrorDocument in Apache for example), this something will be shown. And I consider this method the most preferred as it will handle even parse errors. But you are right, the most common way is setting up an error handler. But by catching the error too early you are making this handler useless. So, either way using try-catch around every query makes very little sense.

Comment: @YourCommonSense that makes sense; I'll keep it in mind for the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

To answer your question using mysqli, you have to use [get_result()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

So, the proper mysqli-based solution will be

```
$query = "SELECT * from `wp_posts` WHERE ID=? ";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $pid);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

(the full explanation for this code can be found in my article, [Mysqli SELECT query with prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select))

and then you can use $data in the foreach loop for the output as it showed in the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

You don't use `bind_result()` with `fetch_array()`. You either make repeated calls to `fetch()` to read the columns into the individual variables bound with `bind_result()` ***OR*** *don't use* `bind_result()`, call `mysqli_smt_get_result()` to pull the results into a `mysqli_result` object, and make repeated calls to `mysqli_fetch_array()` to load the row into your `$row` array.

Since you're using `SELECT *`, the unbound-result approach would be more logical. For your code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = ? ";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)
    or die("Unable to prepare statement: " . $link->error);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $pid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)
    or die("Unable to execute query: " . $stmt->error);

$rslt = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rslt))
{
    ?>
<h2 align="center"> <?php echo $row['post_title']; ?> </h2><br>
<div class="paracenter">

    <p id="cont"><?php echo $row['post_content']; ?></p>
    <hr color="black" width="10%">

</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Just for comparison, here's how you would use `bind_result()` (and also how to use the object syntax):

```
$link = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);
$query = "SELECT post_title, post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = ? ";

$stmt = $link->prepare($query);
    or die("Unable to prepare statement: " . $link->error);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $pid);
$stmt->execute()
    or die("Unable to execute query: " . $stmt->error);
$stmt->bind_result($postTitle, $postContent)
    or die("Unable to bind result: " . $stmt->error);

while($stmt->fetch()){
    ?>
<h2 align="center"> <?php echo $postTitle; ?> </h2><br>
<div class="paracenter">

    <p id="cont"><?php echo $postContent; ?></p>
    <hr color="black" width="10%">

</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Note that when using `bind_result()` your result values are returned as individual scalars rather than in an array, and that you need to bind the result variables to the columns *in order,* so you need to know what columns are in the result.

Hope that helps.

Comment: idk why, when I use the first set of code, the page loads without the data from the db. When I use the second set of code, the page doesn't load

Comment: just slip a note inside `get_result` with `mysqlnd`, some folks have and some don't have it on their env

Comment: First set had a typo which I've corrected, and (as it turns out) so did the second. Try it again.

Comment: @Ghost Good point, the docs for `get_result` don't mention that.

Comment: Do you see any error messages, either in the browser or in the server's `error.log` file?

Comment: I corrected `$rslt = mysqli_statement_get_result($stmt);` to `$rslt = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);`. but still nothing

Comment: on the docs it says `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))`. added the `MYSQLI_NUM` too. still nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109611/discussion-between-yohan-blake-and-darwin-von-corax).

Comment: @Ghost You were right about the order. I must have misinterpreted the docs. Maybe it just means "before you `fetch()`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example of a 'prepared select statement' and echoing out the result.

```
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['pword'])) {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ? && password = ?");// substitute '$conn' with whatever you named your database connection.
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $username = $_POST['uname'];
    $password = $_POST['pword'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows ===0) exit('Not-A-Thing');
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo $row['id'] . "<br>" . $row['username']; }
    $stmt->close();

    }
```

This is just an example. If you were searching for how to bind parameters, then you more than likely already know what the '?'s and 'ss's mean. No explanation should be needed if you have previously queried a database before.