# Prepared Statement Results to Fill HTML table with MySQL Table Fields

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to fill an HTML table with user information like this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
$query = "SELECT * from `users`";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $res->fetch_all();

foreach ($data as $row) 
{
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

It seems the array indices are empty, however, because it results in a number of blank HTML table rows equal to the number of users in the MySQL table.

If I bind_param to the $stmt like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * from `users` WHERE userId = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $userId);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $res->fetch_all();
```

There are no rows created at all in the HTML table, which leads me to believe that the array is empty.

I've gotten this far using information from this answer:

[SELECT * from SQL table using prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732114/select-from-sql-table-using-prepared-statement)

I suppose my issue is in the prepare() parameter, $query. I can't seem to figure out exactly what it is, though.

Comment: `$res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` would return associative results. Default is ordinal columns.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($data)` to see what you fetched? If the array WAS empty, your foreach() wouldn't run AT ALL.

Comment: @apokryfos This works. Mind posting it as an answer so I can accept and upvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$data = $res->fetch_all();
```

to

```
$data = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

This way you will get associative results (e.g. `$row['username']` will work) instead of ordinal results (e.g. `$row[1]`).