# PHP can't retrieve value from HTML form

Tags: php, ajax

I can't seems to retrieve the PHP POST value from the form. The inputs value are being retrieved from Ajax and being inserted into input form below. However, the test on form submission can't retrieve value from the input. May I know what is the issue and how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

UpdateProfile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("dbcon.php"); 

if(isset($_POST['updateProfile']))  
{  
    $profileCode=$_POST['profileCode'];
    $profileName=$_POST['profileName'];
    $profileDesc=$_POST['profileDesc'];
    echo "<script>alert('".$profileCode."')</script>";

    $find_user="select * from profile where profileCode='$profileCode'"; 
    $statement = $dbcon->prepare($find_user);
    $statement->execute();
    if($row = $statement->fetch())
    {  
        echo "<script>alert('".$profileCode."')</script>";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Failed to update profile!')</script>";
    }
} 
?>

<script>
function editBtn(profileCode) {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST", 
                    url: "test.php", 
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: {profileCode:profileCode},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#profileCode').val(data.split(",")[0]);
                        $('#profileName').val(data.split(",")[1]);
                        $('#profileDesc').val(data.split(",")[2]);
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });}
</script>

<?php
 $username = $_SESSION["username"];
 $query = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username='$username'";
 $statement = $dbcon->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
?>
<i class="ti-pencil" onclick="editBtn('<?php echo $row['profileCode']; ?>')"></i>
<?php } ?>
<form role="form" method="post" action="manageprofile.php">
       <label>Profile Code</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="profileCode" name="profileCode" value="" disabled>
       <label>Profile Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" id="profileName" name="profileName" value="" placeholder="Profile Name" required>
       <label>Profile Description</label>
       <textarea rows="5" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="About you" id="profileDesc" name="profileDesc" value=""></textarea>
</form>
```

test.php

```
<?php
include("dbcon.php"); 

$courseCode = $_POST['profileCode'];
$query = " SELECT * FROM profile WHERE profileCode='$profileCode' ";
$statement = $dbcon->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo $row['profileCode'].",".$row['profileName'].",".$row['profileDesc'];
} ?>
```

[Image: Post return no value in alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VifFr.png)

> Error Code : line 7 ($profileCode=$_POST['profileCode'];) //after click on submit

Comment: What does your PHP Error log say?

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of what the output looks like now.

Comment: you need to show us the `test.php` page which is where the AJAX is sending the POSTed data , and/or the manageprofile.php page which is where the form sends the posted data....

Comment: @mulquin no not a screenshot. Code is best.

Comment: `data: {profileCode:profileCode}` Where is `profileCode` set?

Comment: @Martin code of output? He is `alert`ing the output, so a screenshot would work best in this instance.

Comment: @kerbholz ... looks like the user has not associated the input field with the JS variable.

Comment: Your SQL is at risk from SQL Injection attack and needs to be improved **urgently**. You need to [use prepared statements with your variables in the SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36732114/select-from-sql-table-using-prepared-statement)

Comment: @Martin it can't retrieve the POST value.

Comment: It can retrieve data from test.php and display in updateprofile.php, just I cant seems to retrieve the post value from PHP side

Comment: @kerbholz the profileCode is set before this form, there aren't any issues regarding to it.

Comment: @Martin the alert shows no value

Comment: re test.php: `profileCode='$profileCode'` where have you set `$profileCode`?

Comment: @Martin I have updated the updateProfile.php, the profileCode is above the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for helping me. I have think of an solution that uses ajax again to retrieve these updated value and send it to test.php.

UpdateProfile.php

```
function submitEditProfileForm(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST", 
                url: "test.php",
                data: {
                    profileCode:$('#profileCode').val(),
                    profileName:$('#profileName').val(),
                    profileDesc:$('#profileDesc').val()
                },
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

test.php

```
if(isset($_POST['profileCode']) && isset($_POST['profileName']) && isset($_POST['profileDesc'])){
    $profileCode= $_POST['profileCode'];
    $profileName= $_POST['profileName'];
    $profileDesc= $_POST['profileDesc'];
    echo $profileCode.",".$profileName.",".$profileDesc;
```

Answer (score 1):

**The simple answer is that you have disabled your input profileCode** in your html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control border-input" 
id="profileCode" name="profileCode" value="" disabled> <!-- disabled -->
```

That's why `$_POST` doesn't retrieve profileCode.

**Furthermore, you are only sending the value of profileCode in the ajax-request:**

```
data: {profileCode:profileCode}`
```

**So you are sending an ajax-request (post-request) with the data of the profileCode.** The profileCode itself is sent to the PHP. But because PHP doesn't include disabled elements in PHP, the value would be empty.

And therefore the other fields would be empty as well - because your code in test.php:

```
$statement->fetchAll();
```

**would not produce any output at all** and therefore no html response sent back (because profileCode in the query against the db is empty (`SELECT * FROM profile WHERE profileCode=''`))

---

And what other has commented already: **You have to improve how you handle SQL-injections.** You're using prepared statements but you're using them in a way that doesn't protect at all.

I believe you're using PDO-driver so:

**Instead of:**

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username='$username'";
 $statement = $dbcon->prepare($query);
```

**You should use:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username=:username";
$statement = $dbcon->prepare($query);
$statement->execute( array(':username', $username) );
```

This makes it impossible for the user to mess around with the actual string `(SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username=:username)` because `:username` is just a placeholder.

Comment: I have tried alert other fields that aren't disable, but the output is still blank.

Comment: You are also defining dataType as html but you treat the response data as an array (with split()). Are you able to do an alert within the success-part of your ajax?

Comment: yup. this is just some testing, will be converting to json soon

Comment: But data.split(",")[0] (or [1] or [2] would probably be empty as well because you try to split your html into an array (your html has probably no commas in it)

Comment: as the returned value is in form of string(html), it can still be split. The values have been inserted into <input> which has been tested and fully functional. However the problem is that when i submit the form, the POST value couldn't retrieve it.

Comment: However, regarding to $statement->execute( array(':username', $username) ); I have unexpectedly received error. PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: ok. I have changed to $statement->execute( array(':username' => $username) ); and it works. :) thanks

Comment: Forgive me ... Yes you're right. It can be split if there are any html output. But the main issue: if there are not any profilecode given it will be empty. I mean if profileCode=empty then sql would be  SELECT * FROM profile WHERE profileCode='' which would not produce any html output at all and doing a split on an empty html would produce empty values.

Comment: Oh I see. But the problem here is the data has been sent to the form and I could display it but I couldn't retrieve any of it when I submit the form except for using ajax to get it.